# How to view a folder with the name of "."?

Tags: linux, bash, kde, fish, dolphin-file-manager

A folder that is named ".", just dot and nothing else, does not appear in dolphin or krusader file managers.

`ls -a` shows the folder.

Terminal output:

```bash
drwxrwxrwx    - root 29 Feb 17:05 .
drwxrwxrwx    - root 20 Feb 20:32 ..
drwxrwxrwx    - root 20 Feb 17:01 otherFolder1
drwxrwxrwx    - root 20 Feb 20:32 otherFolder2
drwxrwxrwx    - root 20 Feb 17:01 otherFolder3
```

`cd .` does not cd me into the folder as it does for the others. (fish terminal is use)

How can I get such folders to show up on gui file explorers?
How can I `cd` into them?
How can I delete them as `rm -rf .` does not work?

Comment: `.` is the current directory, whereas `..` is the preceding directory

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/767259/108618

Comment: Instead of using `-a`, use `-A` instead, which can be made further helpful via `-AFp` to show directories and files differently. To always hide via `ls` alone, and to colorize files/directories use `-G` or `--color=always` if BusyBox is used _(it'll be one or the other)_: `alias ls="ls -AFpG"` || `alias ls="ls -AFp --color=always"` _(to apply to all terminal sessions, add to the shell RC file [`.bashrc`, `.zshrc`, etc.])_, then update the session by re-sourcing the RC file: `source ~/.<shell>rc`

Comment: So, is it not possible to have a folder with the name "."?

Comment: @Rashiq Not that I'm aware of - you can do `.<name>`, but not only `.` AFAIK, as `mkdir .` will output error `mkdir: .: File exists`

Comment: @JW0914 Would you like to provide this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @JW0914 `eza: Flag -F cannot take a value` is the output of `ls -AFp`. Just to let you know.

Comment: @Rashiq Please execute `ls --help` or `man ls` _(if the program `man` installed)_ to show the help content for the `ls` command _([man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html))_ - you might be using a limited version of BusyBox, as `-F` [shows `/` after directories] is normally supported, and first command will show you what parameters the version of `ls` you're using supports

Comment: @JW0914 According to my help `-F` flag is supported. `ls -AF` worked. It shows `/` after directories and `*` after files. The `p` in `ls -AFp` is what's not working for me. `busybox --version` results in unknown command so I don't think I've it installed in my system.

Comment: Minor digression: it is possible to create files and folders that **appear** to be just `.`, e.g. `NBSP.NBSP`, where NBSP is Chr(160). This is pernicious, and does not seem to be what you asked.

Answer (score 1):

Under UNIX and UNIX-similar operating systems (like Linux), the folder that shows up as `..` in the output of `ls -a` represents the parent folder to the current one, and the folder that shows up as `.` represents the current folder itself. That is,

```
$pwd
/usr/phred/stuff
$ls -al
drwxrwxrwx    - root 29 Feb 17:05 .
drwxrwxrwx    - root 20 Feb 20:32 ..
drwxrwxrwx    - root 20 Feb 17:01 otherFolder1
drwxrwxrwx    - root 20 Feb 20:32 otherFolder2
drwxrwxrwx    - root 20 Feb 17:01 otherFolder3
$cd ..
$pwd
/usr/phred
$ls -al
drwxrwxrwx    - root 29 Feb 17:05 .
drwxrwxrwx    - root 20 Feb 20:32 ..
drwxrwxrwx    - root 20 Feb 17:01 stuff
$cd stuff
$pwd
/usr/phred/stuff
$ls -al
drwxrwxrwx    - root 29 Feb 17:05 .
drwxrwxrwx    - root 20 Feb 20:32 ..
drwxrwxrwx    - root 20 Feb 17:01 otherFolder1
drwxrwxrwx    - root 20 Feb 20:32 otherFolder2
drwxrwxrwx    - root 20 Feb 17:01 otherFolder3
$ls -al ..
drwxrwxrwx    - root 29 Feb 17:05 .
drwxrwxrwx    - root 20 Feb 20:32 ..
drwxrwxrwx    - root 20 Feb 17:01 stuff
$ls -al .
drwxrwxrwx    - root 29 Feb 17:05 .
drwxrwxrwx    - root 20 Feb 20:32 ..
drwxrwxrwx    - root 20 Feb 17:01 otherFolder1
drwxrwxrwx    - root 20 Feb 20:32 otherFolder2
drwxrwxrwx    - root 20 Feb 17:01 otherFolder3
```

I should note that I do not use a graphical file manager on Linux, but I do on Windows, and while the Windows equivalent of the console Linux command `ls -al` does also show the `.` and `..` entries (which have the same meanings as in Linux), the file managers generally do not show them (although the 7-Zip file manager does, and does not appear to allow me to hide them).

Comment: Edit rolled back because this is how it appears on the linuces that I've used.

Comment: Your code content is incorrect, hence the edit. Commands listed _are not_ variables. Separation of content in a code box for _readability_ is important _(why syntax highlighting exists)_ and once commands are correctly listed, the content will be muddled and harder for someone learning to discern what is what. _(The reason why the terminals you've used show content exactly like that is from lacking formatting within the RC file for whatever shell being used, but is not the norm for the vast majority of users - e.g. [this](https://imgur.com/a/W8CaEE8) is how terminals with formatting look)_

Comment: @JW0914 - I have no control over StackExchange's decisions regarding syntax highlighting. The linuces that I have used do not separate output from input with blank lines in the console, and in my "workup" of the commands for this answer, all I did was replace my personal data with made-up or querent-provided results.

Comment: In your terminal, please execute `$pwd`, which is the command in the code box. Simply because the shell you're using doesn't have formatting within the shell's RC file, doesn't mean that's the way it is for everyone else _(it's not)_. This answer will be downvoted if not changed because the commands listed, as currently shown, are _variables_. Unless being used on an embedded system's firmware, all shells apply some sort of formatting and terminals rarely look like the content you've pasted. Please bear in mind this answer is _not_ for you, it's for everyone else.

Comment: @JW0914 - I don't type `$pwd`, I type `pwd` to the prompt `$`, which has no space after it.

Comment: That is not what your pasted content shows - this will be my last reply, as you have enough rep to understand this

Comment: @JW0914 - How do you propose I distinguish - accurately for my system, since I haven't seen others - prompt from command from response?

Comment: You have a 10.2K rep on SO and a 4.5K rep on SU - do you regularly come across terminal output on both SE sites that looks the content pasted? SO is mainly a coding site with most questions or answers containing code boxes.. my first comment explains why this is not the way to show content for readability - how is someone unfamiliar with a terminal supposed to know your _very unique_ terminal formatting setup implies `$` is the prompt and what follows is the command?  As shown, every command in the code box is a variable, because `$<content>` is _always_ a variable, syntax highlighting or not.

Comment: @JW0914 IMO `$ pwd` and `$pwd` may both look like literal commands (or output) for someone who don't know the concept of the prompt. For someone who expects a prompt, they are both pretty clearly a prompt+command. Your edit contained `$ cd stuff & $pws` which is nonsense; for this reason alone it's good the edit was rolled back.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski It's pointless to list individual commands that provide no terminal output on their own new line, as it makes for very inefficient display of code content _(I didn' realize I forgot to seperate the `$`, as that is nonsense)_ - again _readability_ - that portion of the edit isn't the issue here, but by all means leave a user unfamiliar with a terminal to try and figure out why every variable in the code box keeps returning no output or an error, depending on the machine _(most terminals default to a `$` or `#` for prompt)_. Answers are always about others, not ourselves

Comment: @JW0914 What difference does it make? `cd stuff & $pws` runs `cd` in the background (so it cannot do its job in the current shell) and then `$pws` where `$` is certainly not a prompt. And it was `pwd` in the author's original answer. You injected a non-working command and a typo. Alleged improvement of readability does not make the post better when it's accompanied with changing sane commands to nonsense.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski None of which is reason for these comments - please re-read my initial comment and all subsequent comments, as none of my comments are about that. This will be my last reply on this subject, as I clearly stated what the issue is in my initial comment and have repeated it in every comment since. **Answers are about others, not ourselves**

Comment: Yeah... The initial comment starts with "Your code content is incorrect", while it's the code *you* introduced that was incorrect (regardless if one is familiar with the prompt or not).

Comment: There's no point of including `$`s in the 1st place. Just separate the commands/results into few code blocks, then it'll be clear it's prompt with preserved copiability.